# I like to get to the top in SharePoint, Please help me

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am enthusiastic in learning SharePoint, I want to know some detail.

From where should I start learning SharePoint to get expertise.

How should I get to the top in SharePoint?

I want to keep myself always boosted.

Which is the best way to get expertise in SharePoint.

Should we start with coding first or start reading books.

How much time should I allot for each of them?

Any suggestions are invited. I just want to be a very good resource in SharePoint,please share your thoughts with me-Kartheek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to learn SharePoint from books. There are so many aspects to SharePoint, e.g. administration, development, governance, and so many uses like web sites, collaborative sites, document management etc. that are impossible to cover equally. You may find it easier to focus on a specific aspect and dig into that.

IMHO, the best way to learn SharePoint is to try and solve a specific business need with it. Start with a small project and learn the basics. Try different approaches for the same challenge, i.e. UI, SharePoint Designer, out of the box web parts, DVWPs.  And before you start developing code, make sure you have a thorough understanding of SharePoint and what it can do out of the box.

Comment: Hello Teylyn, A very nice reply from you which really is what I think in my mind. For understanding better what I am looking for am explaining these to you, Hope you can suggest me what can be done.

Comment: I am currently working as a SharePoint Developer in a welll reputated organisation, I haven't been involved in any coding for the past one year. I am having Two years of experience.So as I told,I want to know which areas would be the most key areas which are essence for a good developer. When seeing my colleagues doing development in SharePoint I feel very bad because I am doing a support work. I feel that whatever may be the situation I should be pushed down. So now What I actually wanted to know was Which part of SharePoint helps me to have a very strong foundation.

Comment: Well, if you feel that only development makes you a *real* and valuable SharePoint professional, think again. To get started with development set up your environment and start developing. Everything else is just practice.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should first start playing around with SharePoint Foundation. Build sample site collections with few sub sites, experiment with different webparts and design aspects of SharePoint Foundation,Watch video tutorials on youtube(that helped me a lot for a portal development project). That should get you started. Once the initial interest develops you can go in deep. Check out the technical aspects in every process. learn the concept of workflows,taking back ups and also try and figure out the changes in the back end. keep on learning by actually doing stuff. keep increasing the practical knowledge. Reading books doesn't give you the technical edge that actually doing it gives. Keep coding keep building! Best of Luck.

Answer (score 1):

First, download and install Sharepoint Foundation, then start playing with it.
Here is the download link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35488

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn sharepoint is to first identify what you actually want to do in sharepoint, specifically. Administrate entire environments? Design masterpages/sites/templates? Build Solutions and use Visual Studio?) Build applications (like InfoPath, custom web parts, custom lists with custom workflows, etc?)

I started with SharePoint a little over a year ago, and I'm currently focusing more of my research into design and branding, because I'm not a programmer and .Net makes little sense to me. However, I'm good with HTML/CSS/Javascript, so as I get better with branding, I will start to configure asp controls from inside Sharepoint Designer, and start to understand the functions of those controls, to better understand how they work.

In SharePoint, you can try to learn the basics of being a power user first, (there's a book called SharePoint2010 for dummies, you can start there and utilize the index for whenever you run into an issue you're not familiar with. But while you read the book, apply what you see to a test environment!) Become familiar with everything there is to offer and how to use all features that come out of the box, before you start making custom stuff that you'll struggle to find a business case for.

If you want to look into design, ask to have a test site set up where you can mess around with some of your own code. You can find references and how-to's in a multitude of different sources. (Heather Solomon's blog has a very nice CSS reference chart for when you want to start branding, for example.)

Also, try asking your management team what they would recommend you to research into to get to that next level you seek.

If you want to look into administration, it's a bit harder to learn in the workplace, but you can install SharePoint Foundation at home and set up your own environment where you're the owner. There, you'll have access to the files and data stored on the server and know the locations so you can test things that you find on the internet. All of the above, including the previous answers, is what I do/am/doing/will do, and maybe you'll find information here that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Self promotion warning - this is my blog post:

I wrote a blog post a while ago (told you it was self promotion! :) ) on what I think you need to learn: http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/sharepoint-development-what-to-learn.html